# How to post checked statement from HTML to JS file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I can't post checked statement from HTML to JS file

```
{{#each readValues }}
    <br>
    Plug: {{@index}} => {{this}}
    <input type='checkbox' class="plug" onclick="sendNudes();" />
{{/each}}
```

This is my Handlebars code and I tried to

```js
<script>
    function sendNudes(){
      var plug = document.getElementsByClassName('plug');
      if(plug[0].checked) {
        alert('plug 0');
      }
      if(plug[1].checked) {
        alert('plug 1');
      }
.
.
.
```

I am trying to reach checked value here and post it to JS but I don't know how.

Genereted HTML:

```
    <br>
    Plug: 0 => 1
    <input type='checkbox' class="plug" onclick="sendNudes();" />
    <br>
    Plug: 1 => 1
    <input type='checkbox' class="plug" onclick="sendNudes();" />
    <br>
    Plug: 2 => 1
    <input type='checkbox' class="plug" onclick="sendNudes();" />
    <br>
     ...
```

```
    <script>
    function sendNudes(){
      var plug = document.getElementsByClassName('plug');
      if(plug[0].checked) {
        alert('plug 0');
      }
      if(plug[1].checked) {
        alert('plug 1');
      }
      if(plug[2].checked) {
      ...
```

Comment: Do have an example of the generated HTML ?

Comment: I posted it now

Answer (score 0):

It would be more beneficial to bind an event handler to your checkboxes using event listeners than passing an anonymous function using the inline `onclick` attribute.

Furthermore, you could add a value to the checkboxes if you plan to do something with it. Certainly will make your life easier.

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('plug');

for (var i=0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].addEventListener('click', sendNudes, false);
}

function sendNudes(event) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    console.log('checked:', event.target.value)
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked:', event.target.value)
  }
}
```

```html
Plug: 0 => 1
<input type='checkbox' class="plug" value="1" />
<br>
Plug: 1 => 1
<input type='checkbox' class="plug" value="2" />
<br>
Plug: 2 => 1
<input type='checkbox' class="plug" value="3" />
```

Comment: but, is this js code embedded in HTML or can I use it in app.js file?